# C# About borders and behaviors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to make a smart control on a windows forms application.

First there is a normal button ("Big Button"). On `MouseHover`, it will hide itself and at the same time a panel will appear. Inside of the panel there are four small buttons. They each represent a "Quick Action". When the mouse leaves the panel, the Big Button should appear and the panel itself should hide.

**The Panel**

The panel is a normal UserControl. It contains four normal buttons (nested buttons) with borders.

*It is only visible while the mouse is hovering the panel.*

[image]

**The Big Button**

The big button is just a normal button. It is visible (and clickable), but only while the `MouseHover` Event is not fired.

[image: Big Button]

**The Problem**

The problem is that I can not catch the `MouseLeave` event of `the panel`. This is because it has got nested buttons in it, which means every time the mouse moves over a nested button, the `MouseLeave` event of `the panel` would be fired.

**One Approach**

I tried to prevent this by implementing the `MouseLeave` event of `the nested buttons` AND `the panel`. Every time the `MouseLeave` event gets fired, I check if the mouse is still inside of `the panel`'s rectangle.

**The bug**

The approach described in the previous paragraph works nice, but there is one problem. Every time the mouse is over a border (mainly of `the nested buttons`), the `MousePosition` catched by the `MouseLeave` event is wrong. Usually it is somewhere in a negative and random place.

I check the `MousePosition` with the following code:

> panelRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(MousePosition))

(The `MousePosition` is from the form's sight, but this does not explain why the position is negative some times, if the nested buttons are in the middle of the form).

**The Question**

How can I see if the mouse is inside the panel? The main problem are the borders. Why is my `MousePosition` at a random place when the mouse is positioned over the border of a nested button?

Here is some other code:

```
        bool bInsideRectangle = 
        Rectangle panelRectangle = new Rectangle(this.panelContainer.Location, this.panelContainer.Size);

        if (panelRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)) || PointToClient(Control.MousePosition).X < 0 || PointToClient(Control.MousePosition).Y < 0)
        {
            bInsideRectangle = true;
        }

        //bool bIsInsideOfPanel = this.panelContainer.ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Control.MousePosition));
        //bool bIsInsideOfButton1 = this.button1.ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Control.MousePosition));
        //bool bIsInsideOfButton2 = this.button2.ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Control.MousePosition));
        //bool bIsInsideOfButton3 = this.button3.ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Control.MousePosition));
        //bool bIsInsideOfButton4 = this.button4.ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Control.MousePosition));

        // Check if the mouse is not inside of those child-controls.
        if(!bInsideRectangle)
        //if (!bIsInsideOfPanel && !bIsInsideOfButton1 && !bIsInsideOfButton2 && !bIsInsideOfButton3 && !bIsInsideOfButton4)
        {
            this.panelContainer.Visible = false;
            this.buttonBig.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: Out of interest, is there a reason you can't use WPF for this?

Comment: Because this is not a very small project :) And it has been on the work for quite some time now.

Comment: A very common question.  There is no clean solution for this, you have no guarantee that the panel's MouseLeave event will fire when the cursor leaves a button.  Reported mouse positions do not cover every single pixel traveled.  The Capture property was designed to solve this, but it can't work when you have nested buttons.  The workaround is to poll, using a Timer that you enable on MouseEnter.  In the Tick event handler, check if the cursor is still within the Panel.

Comment: But in theory I can catch the MouseLeave of every single nested button, and the panel itself. When the MouseLeave event is fired, I go and check the MousePosition and see if it is inside of the panel. The problem is that when the mouse is over the border of a nested button, the mouse position shows somewhere else, for example in the coordinate X= **-84** (WHY NEGATIVE?!) Y=265.

Answer (score 0):

Create a little helper that tells you if the mouse is in bounds of the control

```
// The helper relies on "MousePosition" member of the form
// so this function has to be in the form, or you find another way to do the check
bool isMouseInControl(Control control)
{
    return control.ClientRectangle.Contains(control.PointToClient(MousePosition));
}
```

Now bind both MouseEnter and MouseLeave to your big button

```
bigButton.MouseEnter += bigButton_MouseEnter;
bigButton.MouseLeave += bigButton_MouseLeave;
```

Remember the current state of the submenu (bool) `bool submenu = false;`

Now you can check for a correct leave/enter like this:

```
    void bigButton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(submenu && !isMouseInControl(sender as Control))
        {
            submenu = false;
            // Disable submenu here
        }
    }


    void bigButton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(submenu || isMouseInControl(sender as Control))
        {
            submenu = true;
            // Enable submenu here
        }
    }
```

The `bool submenu` is optional as it only prevents checking when it is not needed (and as far as I can see it only does for the mouseenter anyway...)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. The problem is not with the big button. As soon as the mouse hovers the big button, it is set invisible, and the panel with the submenus is set visible. Now I don't know if the mouse has left the panel with the quick-action buttons or not, because I can't catch the MouseLeave from above the quick-action-buttons.

Comment: @ElMac Suggestion: In the MouseEnter handler attach the MouseMove and keep checking until you leave the box, then detach the MouseMove listener again. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, that is a similar approach to mine. The main problem is that the mouse position gets displayed wrong if the mouse crosses a border (for example the one of a nested button). I think this might be a bug of .NET, because I can't think of a reason why my mouse position is negative on the X-Axis.

Comment: Are you using my isMouseInControl with the sender? Then your sender is probably one of the child buttons and the coordinate spaces are different. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I almost tought that was the solution. But I was using the Panel as control. Since the controls are inside of this panel, it is theoretically not possible that the nested buttons are in a negative location. Practically it is apparently. Either there is really a bug, or I am missing something.

Comment: @ElMac I just noticed that in the "MouseEnter"-Handler there really is no need to check if the mouse is inside the control...Also your question doesn't seem to include that you are hiding the control. Can you edit your question? I added another answer to the "hidden control" question you asked in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution to **your** problem. This works just fine for one (1) big button, but is not very extensible.

First we attach the mouse enter handler (assuming `bigButton` is the big button object) `bigButton.MouseEnter += bigButton_MouseEnter;`

Here is the Enter handler

```
void bigButton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Hide the button
    bigButton.Visible = false;
    // Listen for position changes.
    // We have to do that on the form, because the
    // button is hidden and won't get notified
    MouseMove += bigButton_MouseMove;
}
```

Now do the checking for "leaving the big button area"

```
void bigButton_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // This check relies on the MousePosition member of the form
    // You can avoid that by substracting e.Location by the bigButton's location
    if(!bigButton.ClientRectangle.Contains(bigButton.PointToClient(MousePosition)))
    {
        // Detach handler
        MouseMove -= Form1_MouseMove;
        // Show control again
        button1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not mention the big button's visibility, because this is not the problem. Hiding it is already working, the only problem is that the nested buttons wont let me check the MouseLeave-Event of the panel containing them. And I tried to fix this problem listening to the nested buttons events, but the border of them change the mouse position in the code (apparently it's a bug). I will try to formulate my question better. Thanks for the help though!